# Fabric.js : Is there any issue for creating multiple objects using only one variable?

Tags: javascript, object, fabricjs

- Why do I question about this ?

Because, from my code, I want user to create unlimited images so they must be created in shorter way like using one variable for all.

This is my code from the function called when a user added an image:

**(EDITED : This code is now fixed.)**

```
function addImage(){
    var imageAdded = new Image();
    imageAdded.onload = function (img) {
    var imgAdded = new fabric.Image(imageAdded, {
        clipName: picID,
        clipTo: function (ctx) {
            return _.bind(clipByName, imgAdded)(ctx)
        }
    });
    canvas.add(imgAdded);
    };
    var n = 0;
    if(n == 0){
        n = 1;
        addEventListenerFabric();
    }
}
function addEventListenerFabric(){
    canvas.on("object:selected", function (e) {
        alert(e.target.clipName + " is selected"); // fixed
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
}
```

- What's the problem in my code ?

My code will alert according to the amount of images there are. For example, if a user creates 3 images, it will alert 3 times when he select an image. **Is it because of using one variable for all ?** (Maybe my code is simply wrong, please recheck)

- If it is impossible to use one variable for all or if you have better solution.
  I will be very interested to see your comments.

Thank you in advice !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you bind `object:selected` to canvas on each image load. Just move it out from the `onload` function and it will trigger only once.

Comment: Thank you !, I tried this with my code but things remains the same, alerting multiple time. I had edited my code for better vision.

Comment: @Mes i tried given code in jsFiddle with some modifications to replicate multiple image addition using single Image object (from the given example it's unclear how do you load it) and I have no any problems with selection. You can check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lsn2kcrf/ It looks like your problem could be outside described example.

Comment: Your code gave me a clue to fix this !. So, I just noticed a simple thing that the eventListener must be called only 1 time, while in my code, it is called everytime an image added. Thanks to jsfiddle for giving me a learning methods for beginnner about when to add things up.